# Vue Meta - Title not displayed properly when filled with dynamic data value

Tags: vue.js, meta-tags, vue-meta

I have a pretty basic setup in my Vue app for my blog, where I have `/blog`, which is a listing of my blog posts, and then `/blog/:slug`, where slug is the slog for the individual post (e.g. `mysite.com/blog/my-awesome-blog-post`. I'm using `vue-meta` for the meta tags, and everything works great - for everything except the tag for the individual blog posts. My setup is:

App.vue

```
export default {
  metaInfo: {
    title: 'Building great web experiences',
    titleTemplate: 'My Website | %s',
  },
  meta: [
    { charset: 'utf-8' },
    { name: 'description', content: 'The website for my organization' },
    { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }
  ]
}
```

Blog.vue

```
export default {
  metaInfo: {
    title: 'Blog Home'
  },
```

BlogPost.vue (following the [vue-meta docs](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/faq/component-props.html))

```
export default {
data() {
  metaDescription: '',
},
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: this.post.data.title,
      meta: [
        { vmid: 'description', name: 'description', content: this.metaDescription}
      ]
    }
  },

...
methods: {
    getPost() {
      const vm = this;
      butter.post
        .retrieve(this.$route.params.slug)
        .then(res => {
          vm.post = res.data;
          vm.metaDescription = vm.post.data.summary;
        })
        .catch(res => {
          console.log(res);
        });
    }
  },
```

The problem is that when I go to a blog post page, the title metatag is still `My Site | Blog Home`, instead of `My Site | My Awesome Blog Post`. If I put a static string in for `title`, it works fine. And, if I inspect the  object returned by the `metaInfo()` function in the Vue devtools, it shows `title` with the appropriate value. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? According to the docs this is "easy", but it doesn't seem that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my [comment in the GitHub issue I filed](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/issues/533#issuecomment-602289924), I made a small change that worked (actually, there were a couple that worked). The first was to create a data variable called `metaTitle`, fill it in `getPost()`, and use that in `metaInfo()`:

```
data() {
    return {
      post: {},
      metaTitle: '',
      metaDescription: ''
    };
  },
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: this.metaTitle,
      meta: [
        { vmid: 'description', name: 'description', content: this.metaDescription}
      ]
    }
  },
 methods: {
    getPost() {
      const vm = this;
      butter.post
        .retrieve(this.$route.params.slug)
        .then(res => {
          vm.post = res.data.data;
          vm.metaTitle = vm.post.data.title;
          vm.metaDescription = vm.post.summary;
        })
        .catch(res => {
          console.log(res);
        });
    }
  },
```

I then also tried another twist and made my post object one level smaller:

```
.then(res => {
  vm.post = res.data.data;
  vm.metaTitle = vm.post.data.title;
  vm.metaDescription = vm.post.summary;
})
```

and used it in metaInfo():

```
metaInfo() {
  return {
    title: this.post.title,
    meta: [
      { vmid: 'description', name: 'description', content: this.metaDescription}
    ]
  }
},
```

Maybe the issue is that the `title` data can't be too many levels down in an object? Not sure, but either way works.